# Postgresql and MS Access unable to insert new data

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I have a Postgresql server with a data base and table, columns dont matter. My issue is my primary key is set to BIGSERIAL, it auto-increments. However, on MS ACCESS when I create a form to insert new entrys - I am unable to do so unless I enter a digit into the bigserial ID field. It will not automatically increment.

I've tried playing with the enabled and locked settings in Access with no luck.

Found this person with same issue that seemed to never have been resolved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065130/how-to-use-serial-autonumber-in-a-postgresql-access-combination

Answer (score 1):

Either insert DEFAULT (unquoted) for that column, or specify the list of columns being inserted and omit the primary key column from that list.